# Java Stream: transform user input to batches

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I would like to stream ints (from user input) and output a stream of lists of specific length - effectively batching the user's input to batches and then doing some other work on it. 
So Basically, for the user input : `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` I could split it to these batches  `<1,2,3> , <4,5,6> , <7,8,9>` As soon as I collect 3 numbers, I want to create a list for the next processing step to work on. 
I am trying to do this using lamda and stream operations in java 8 in order to learn more of it.

the only related sample I could find is this http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/07/grouping-sampling-and-batching-custom.html with the custom collector that does something very similiar to what I want - the problem with using a collector is that I don't want to wait for the end of the stream, but process each batch as it is ready.

Is there some easy way to do it? Is it somehow not suitable to use Java 8 streams for this kind of operation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general it's problematic to solve your problem using Java-8 stream API. First, splitting the stream to fixed-size batches is impossible for parallel streams as the source might divide the task at some unknown offset, so you can not know in general case the index of current stream element until you actually process all the previous subtasks (which will kill the whole idea of parallelization). As Stream API idea is to work identically in parallel and sequential modes, it simply has no method to combine the stream elements into even batches. There are some third-party solutions which usually ignore the existence of parallel streams (like [protonpack](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack) `StreamUtils.windowed`), but in general it's cleaner to generate batches from the very beginning instead of transforming the stream.

The second problem is that there's no ready facility in Java-8 to get the numbers (or at least tokens) from standard input as a Stream (you can only get lines using `BufferedReader.lines()`). It will be somewhat better in Java-9 as stream support is added to `Scanner` class (see [JDK-8072722](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072722)), but currently you need to do some extra steps.

Finally if you managed to create the Stream of number batches, you'll need to finish it as soon as standard input finishes. It's the job for `takeWhile` operation which also will appear in Java-9 only (see [JDK-8071597](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8071597)).

I can afford a solution involving my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library, though I still don't like it much:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[\n\r,\\s]+");
Iterable<String> iterable = () -> sc;
// Supplier which returns Lists of up to 3 numbers from System.in
Supplier<List<Integer>> triples = () -> StreamEx.of(iterable.spliterator())
        .map(Integer::valueOf).limit(3).toList();
StreamEx.generate(triples).takeWhile(list -> !list.isEmpty())
        // replace with your own stream operations
        // they will be executed as soon as three numbers are entered
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The main feature of StreamEx used here is `StreamEx.takeWhile` which is the backport of Java-9 `Stream.takeWhile`.

If you prefer using [jOOL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL), it would be even simpler:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[\n\r,\\s]+");
Supplier<List<Integer>> triples = () -> Seq.seq(sc).map(Integer::valueOf).limit(3).toList();
Seq.generate(triples).limitUntil(List::isEmpty)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The idea is the same. `Spliterator` creation is unnecessary here as jOOL has `Seq.seq(Iterator)` method.

Finally here's protonpack solution. I personally don't like this library, but the solution looks quite short, so somebody might prefer it:

```
import static com.codepoetics.protonpack.StreamUtils.*;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("[\n\r,\\s]+");
Stream<List<Integer>> stream = takeUntil(windowed(
    stream(() -> sc).map(Integer::valueOf), 3, 3), List::isEmpty);
stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The problem here is that it delays the processing of the batch for some reason until the next batch is formed. Also it does not create the final batch if it has less than 3 elements. This problem is [fixed](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack/pull/18) in the trunc, but is not released yet.